# install optimise with npm from optimist.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, mapbox

Trying to fix an offline install of the [Carto tool from Mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/carto) on Ubuntu 14.04. Currently, node is giving me an error, it cant find the `optimist` module. I can manually find an `optimist.js` file, but its not under a "proper" node_modules directory like the other Carto dependancies are (e.g. `underscore`). I'm **very** new to npm and node, so my question is "is there a way to properly install optimise from this `optimist.js` file I have?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to *use* the package,

```
$ npm install -g carto
```

should be enough to get you started. Note that you might need to use `sudo` for that command.

Node.js is centered around a package manager called ["npm"](https://www.npmjs.com/). Every npm project has a package.json at its root directory that specifies its dependencies, package name, version, et al. By looking at [carto's package.json](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/package.json#L39-L43) even if you installed optimist successfully you will encounter some more `require` errors.

If you want to develop the package, after cloning it with Git run

```
$ npm install
```

inside the directory. That will install all dependencies (including `devDependencies` that are not installed when you are installing the package itself) for you.

There are plenty of tutorials on how Node.js works, like http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html. Those should give you a more comprehensive view than this answer.

With a proper package manager like npm, you should never using a random script found on the internet to fake it as a module.

Good luck!

---

**UPDATE** now that one knows how npm works, if you want to make it available locally to be installed, you can do something like this

```bash
# With Internet
# Make a cache
$ mkdir carto-cache
# Make a temporary directory where the initial copy of carto is installed
$ mkdir to-be-discarded
$ cd to-be-discarded
# Now install the package, and cache the package in carto-cache
$ npm install --cache ../carto-cache --prefix . carto
# You can now remove to-be-discarded, and copy carto-cache to wherever you want.

# Without internet
$ npm install --cache carto-cache --cache-min 999999999 -g carto
```

(derived from https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2568)

Comment: Great advise. So, what would be the cleanest way to download all the required carto packages for a full offline install? Does npm provide a way to, say, get all dependencies when online then later I can do `npm install -g /path/to /offline/carto` packages?

Comment: Just a small update. This worked perfectly. All I needed to do before it worked was delete the old carto  directory.